# Docker's heredoc example for RUN is not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, heredoc

I tried to implement the example provided by Docker itself (https://www.docker.com/blog/introduction-to-heredocs-in-dockerfiles/)

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs

FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN <<EOF
echo "Hello" >> /hello
echo "World!" >> /hello
EOF
```

using docker version

```
~/test$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b
```

but it throws the error

```
~/test$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 6: unknown instruction: ECHO
```

I've also tried it with dockerfile versions 1, 1.3, 1.4, 2, 2.0. Nothing worked. Am I doing something wrong or is it just not working (yet)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the buildkit toolkit for that:

```
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the answer provided by @Paolo, you may use

```bash
docker buildx build .
```

which uses the buildkit by default, but works on any OS. See [the official docker annoncement](https://www.docker.com/blog/introduction-to-heredocs-in-dockerfiles/).